# find method of moments estimator from this pdf

Tags: statistical-inference, density-function

Let the pdf of $x$ be defined by
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &\mbox{ } elsewhere\ \\ 
\frac{4x}{\theta^2} & \mbox{for }0 < x \le\frac{\theta}{2} \\\frac{-4x}{\theta^2}+\frac{4}{\theta} & \mbox{for }\frac{\theta}{2}<x\le\theta  \end{cases} $$ with $0<\theta\le2$
Find an estimator of $\theta$ by method of moments

I started computing the expected value of the first piece
$$E(X_1) = \int_{0}^\frac{\theta}{2} x\frac{4x}{\theta^2}= \frac{\theta}{6}$$
and then for the second piece I get
$$E(X_2) = \int_{\frac{\theta}{2}}^\theta x(\frac{-4x}{\theta^2}+\frac{4}{\theta})= \frac{\theta}{3}$$
at the end I added the two pieces together $E(X_1)+E(X_2)$ and got $\frac{\theta}{2}$ and equating it to $\bar X$ I got $\theta_{MOM} = 2\bar X$ is this the right approach  to find method of moments when there are two domain to consider?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your computations are correct and you have the correct method of moments estimator, but the explanation is somewhat imprecise.  The reason is that you have not defined what you mean by $X_1$ and $X_2$.  Rather,
$$\operatorname{E}[X] = \int_{x=0}^{\theta} x f_X(x) \, dx = \int_{x=0}^{\theta/2} x \cdot \frac{4x}{\theta^2} \, dx + \int_{x=\theta/2}^\theta x \left(\frac{4}{\theta} - \frac{4x}{\theta^2} \right) \, dx,$$ directly.  There is no need to perform the computations separately nor introduce auxiliary random variables.  The problem with saying something like
$$\operatorname{E}[X_1] = \int_{x=0}^{\theta/2} x \cdot \frac{4x}{\theta^2} \, dx$$ is that on the interval $x \in [0, \theta/2]$, the function $4x/\theta^2$ is not a proper density:  $$\int_{x=0}^{\theta/2} \frac{4x}{\theta^2} \, dx = \frac{1}{2},$$ whereas if $X_1$ were an actual random variable, this expression would have to integrate to $1$.

Alternatively, what you can write is
$$\operatorname{E}[X] = \operatorname{E}[X \mid X \le \theta/2]\Pr[X \le \theta/2] + \operatorname{E}[X \mid X > \theta/2]\Pr[X > \theta/2],$$ and now if we define
$$X_1 = X \mid X \le \theta/2, \quad X_2 = X \mid X > \theta/2,$$ these have densities
$$f_{X_1}(x) = \frac{8x}{\theta^2}, \quad f_{X_2}(x) = \frac{8}{\theta} - \frac{8x}{\theta^2}.$$  But this is all rather circuitous because as I already pointed out, the first equation I wrote suffices.  It is the same as saying, for instance, if we have any piecewise function, say
$$h(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x < 0 \\ 1, & 0 \le x \le 1, \\ x, & 1 < x \le 2, \end{cases}$$

then $$\int_{x=0}^2 h(x) \, dx = \int_{x=0}^1 1 \, dx + \int_{x=1}^2 x \, dx.$$

Comment: thank you very much for this clear explanation! just a last question what if $$h(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x < 0 \\ 1, & 0 \le x \le 1, \\ x, & 2 < x \le 3 \end{cases}$$ in this case the domain is not "continuos from $0$ to $2$? Can I still find the expected value by adding the 2 pieces together?

Comment: $h$ is not a density; it is just an example of any piecewise function that, if you were to integrate on some interval, is split up over those pieces where the function is nonzero.  So if $h$ is defined as you have done, then for instance, $$\int_{x=1/2}^{5/2} h(x) \, dx = \int_{x=1/2}^1 1 \, dx + \int_{x=2}^{5/2} x \, dx,$$ assuming that $h(x) = 0$ for $1 < x \le 2$.

Comment: thank you very much for this clear explanation